# Contact Form 7 Get Image Function

Tags: plugins, forms, images, contact

I am building our website and we are a business that sells dresses.
I am looking to have an "Inquire" button for every dress that we have (we avoid posting prices).

My dilemma is that a regular contact / inquiry form will not do, as we need to determine which particular dress the customer is inquiring about, thus we need a copy of the image within the message that we receive via the contact form.

How can this be achieved in Contact Form 7? I believe it is the most flexible contact form. thank you

Best,
Kevin

Comment: the form is on the product page or on another page ?

Comment: I am hoping it can be on the actual product page, maybe below a few lines of description about the dress. This means that every product will have the form on the same spot.

Comment: on the same page, you can retrieve meta values on the product with that : https://contactform7.com/getting-default-values-from-the-context/

Comment: Does it work for images?